# Why doesn't my message fade out as expected?

Tags: html, jquery, flask, flash

I'm trying to use jQuery to let the notification fade in and fade out automatically. However, the jQuery is not working at all and I have to manually close the notification. May I know what is the problem?

**The script and bootstrap that I have linked**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**The notification**

```
{% with loggedout = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=["loggedout"]) %}
{% if loggedout %}
    {%- for msg in loggedout %}
    <div class="position-relative">
        <div class="rightbtm flash">
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <h4>Logged Out Successfully!</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button> 
                <p>{{ msg }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor -%}
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

```
<script>
    $(function() {
       $('.flash').delay(500).fadeIn('normal', function() {
          $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut();
       });
    });
</script>
```

**The notification on right bottom corner**

[image]

```js
$(function() {
  $('.flash').delay(500).fadeIn('normal', function() {
    $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
The notification

<div class="position-relative">
  <div class="rightbtm flash">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <h4>Logged Out Successfully!</h4>
      
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      
      <p>{{ msg }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the redundant and very old version 1.9 of jQuery.
2. Use the full version of jQuery 3. Slim doesn't have effects functions.
3. You apparently don't need the `fadeIn()` function as you're disabling it with `'normal'` as a duration. Just use `show()`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.flash').delay(500).show(function() {
    $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="p-2">
  <div class="rightbtm flash">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <h4>Logged Out Successfully!</h4>
      
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      
      <p>{{ msg }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```